# Exceljs vs SheetJs

Tags: exceljs, sheetjs

I'm working with xlsx file. I've foudn 2 great libraries for it

1. ExcelJS
2. Sheetjs (Community Edition / ProEdition)

But I'm not able to decide between them. Which obne should I choose ?
I've looked into the comparision of their features but haven't found any such comparisions. Mostly the comparisions are based on no of start, how old are they, how frequenctly they are updated etc, but nothing on their features.

https://www.libtrends.info/npm-compare/exceljs-vs-xlsx

https://www.libhunt.com/compare-exceljs-vs-sheetjs

https://npmcompare.com/compare/exceljs,node-xlsx,xlsx.

Are they not difference in their features ? What about Pro - Community Edit of Sheetjs ?

Answer (score 9):

I do not think there right or wrong on both.

From a dev perspective SheetJs is simpler, smoother.
Reading we are sheetjs due to its simplicity.
Writing we are using exceljs to not be confronted to something only available on the pro package.

Generation wise we are right now facing performance issues with exceljs for more advanced excels. We are looking to take a look for sheetjs and eventually the pro version as our business rely more and more a nice looking excel.

Hope it helps.